# What is the difference between using an ipc:/// and ipc:// transport-class specifier in ZeroMQ?

Tags: url, ipc, zeromq

I have seen instances where the **`ipc`** URL has two and three slashes.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

**`ipc:///`** is an absolute path, i.e. **`ipc:///tmp/tmp.pipe`**,
and
 **`ipc://`** is a relative path.

Take **`PUB/SUB`** for example, if your publisher and subscriber are in same directory, then it works using relative path. Otherwise you should use absolute path to make sure your publisher and subscriber find the same path.